# SpringBoot Controller error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to create Spring Boot "Car rental" application, that will connect with database, so I can use simple operations like GET, POST, etc to test it. I've created 3 tables : **Cars**, **Clients** and **Rentals** (where rentals has foreign keys to client's and car's ids). But this is the error that I'm getting:

```
2017-06-13 22:22:59.238 ERROR 8044 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in eu.fitk.controllers.CarsController required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.
```

and this is how my **CarsController** class looks like:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/cars")
public class CarsController {

    private final CarsRepository carsRepository;

    public CarsController(CarsRepository carsRepository){
        this.carsRepository = carsRepository;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void addCar(@RequestBody Cars car){
        carsRepository.save(car);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Cars> getCars(){
        return carsRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

I tried to add @Autowired annotation above **CarsController** constructor, but it didn't help, I'm new to Spring Boot and I don't really fully get how it is configurated.

**pom.xlm** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>eu.fitk</groupId>
    <artifactId>car-rental-application</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>car-rental-application</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

**Cars** entities class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="cars")
public class Cars {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    private String brand,model,licence_plate_number,production_year,price_per_day;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getBrand() {
        return brand;
    }

    public void setBrand(String brand) {
        this.brand = brand;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public String getLicence_plate_number() {
        return licence_plate_number;
    }

    public void setLicence_plate_number(String licence_plate_number) {
        this.licence_plate_number = licence_plate_number;
    }

    public String getProduction_year() {
        return production_year;
    }

    public void setProduction_year(String production_year) {
        this.production_year = production_year;
    }

    public String getPrice_per_day() {
        return price_per_day;
    }

    public void setPrice_per_day(String price_per_day) {
        this.price_per_day = price_per_day;
    }
}
```

**CarsRepository** class

```
public interface CarsRepository extends JpaRepository<Cars, Integer> {

}
```

**CarRentalApplication** class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class CarRentalApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CarRentalApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**application.properties** file

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/car_rental
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

If any other class or file is needed to find the issue, let me know and I will edit the post right away. Thank you in advance :)

**PS. i read somewhere that using:**

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

dependencies is not needed, when i'm already using

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

already. Now i'm getting this kind of error:

```
2017-06-13 22:21:52.194 ERROR 8176 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1078) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at eu.fitk.CarRentalApplication.main(CarRentalApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147) [idea_rt.jar:na]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:954) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:882) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353) ~[spring-orm-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370) ~[spring-orm-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359) ~[spring-orm-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: eu.fitk.entities.Cars, at table: rentals, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(car)]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:431) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:398) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:225) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:595) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:265) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:329) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:443) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    ... 27 common frames omitted
```

**Rentals** class with mapping:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="rentals")
public class Rentals {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    private Date date_of_rental;
    private String status;

    //instances of client and car classes
    private Clients client;
    private Cars car;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Date getDate_of_rental() {
        return date_of_rental;
    }

    public void setDate_of_rental(Date date_of_rental) {
        this.date_of_rental = date_of_rental;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="client_id")
    public Clients getClient() {
        return client;
    }

    public void setClient(Clients client) {
        this.client = client;
    }


    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="car_id")
    public Cars getCar() {
        return car;
    }

    public void setCar(Cars car) {
        this.car = car;
    }
}
```

Comment: you should show the Spring configuration class.

Comment: did you added annotation on service , repository,controller class.

Comment: Do you have an interface CarsRepository? What does it look like?

Comment: "If any other class or file is needed to find the issue, let me know and I will edit the post right away. " As said in my initial comment  : you should show the Spring configuration class.

Comment: I thought you mean pom.xml file :D What do you mean then? the application.properties file?

Comment: ok that was a dumb question, pom.xml is of course Maven configuration file, I added Main class (CarRentalApplication) to post description which contains SpringBootApplication annotation which i think has Configuration annotation inside aswell. Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate doesn't handle annotations added both on fields and on methods very well. Just move all the hibernate annotations either on fields either on methods in your entities.

Comment: i edited my post to show my application.properties file, i think it was configured well

Comment: Could you please add more information about your stack trace? Isn't there any information before it can't find entityManagerFactory? Usually, it shows the reason why the missing bean can't be constructed.

Comment: Before deleting the Hibernate dependencies error was like this: 2017-06-13 22:20:29.228 ERROR 7232 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : , but now it is different, as shown in my edit

Comment: Seems that your mapping in Rental class is incorrect. Could you please show the Rental class?

Comment: Ok added. It is very likely wrong, i did it following some tutorial and I had no idea how to check if it is correct or not.

Comment: Try to remove @ JoinColumn annotations in Rentals class and run the app. If it doesn't work - try to put @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn instead

Comment: tried both, none of them worked, still the same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146575/discussion-between-dzatorsky-and-tyler-durden).

Answer (score 0):

Use Hibernate reverse engineering concept to generate Java persistent entities from database tables in eclipse